# Simplifying and enhancing readability in time angle calculation

Tags: python

Is the following Python code, which calculates hand angles based on current time, simple and readable?

What alternative approaches can enhance simplicity and readability? Are there concise one-liner solutions worth considering?

```py
def calculate_angles(current_time: List[int]) -> List[float]:
    ''' Calculates hands angles '''
    hours, minutes, seconds = current_time
    return [hours_angle(hours, minutes),
            minutes_angle(minutes),
            seconds_angle(seconds)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't bad, it's perfectly serviceable code.

The docstring should be an English sentence.
Each sentence ends with a `.` period.

Representing `current_time` as a sequence rather than a
[time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#time-objects)
object is perhaps suspect.
You might want to reconsider that design choice.

Thank you kindly for including those optional type annotations.

The signature ends with `... List[int]) -> List[float]:`,
which arguably is wrong, or at least not pythonic.
We prefer to use a `tuple` (a 3-tuple, here)
rather than a `list` of arbitrary length
to represent what amounts to a C struct.
While you're at it, make it a
[namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

The rule is pretty simple.
Use a tuple when position dictates meaning, e.g. unpacking h, m, s.
Use a list for variable number of "the same kind" of thing,
for example a bunch of h,m,s transaction timestamps.

---

Let's talk about computing those angles.

The `hours_angle` and `minutes_angle` signatures
look a little suspect to me.
They omit `seconds`, or rather they implicitly
treat it as zero seconds.
I guess that for *some* clocks that's the appearance they offer.
I would be happier if we were passing a `time` object
into these helpers and letting each helper decide
if it implements a clock style which prohibits
movement of the other hands for sixty seconds.

Usually I'm a big fan of "make it smaller!", "extract more helpers!".
But here I wonder if we've maybe gone too far in that direction.
Computing total seconds can look a bit like
[Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method):

```
    seconds_since_midnight = ((h) * 60 + m) * 60 + s
```

With that representation in hand we might multiply by a conversion factor of six:

```
    degrees_since_midnight = seconds_since_midnight * 360 / 60
```

and then reverse the process to pick out h,m,s degrees.
A single helper that returns a 3-tuple
might be more convenient and accurate than the three helpers that OP proposes.